# Set instance variable as default parameter to class function

Tags: python, class

I have a class function that takes 4 arguments, all class member variables in practice. Usually only one of these arguments is modified at a time and the rest of the time the would-be defaults (current values of the class member variables) are passed to the function/written out even though they aren't changing.

I thought the best would be to make these class member variables the defaults, but I'm having a hard time getting the best syntax. The following code produces behavior I desire - using a class member variable as a default parameter to a function. But it's ugly:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def testfunc(self, param = None):
        if not param:
            param = self.a
        print(param)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a1 = test(1, 3)
    a1.testfunc()
    a2 = test(5, 5)
    a2.testfunc()
   #(prints 1 and 5 when called)
```

I would like to use the following:

```
    def testfunc(self, param = self.a):
        print(param)
```

But this gives the error:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

What's a better way to do this?

Comment: The best way to do this *is* `param=None` then `if param is None:` (note testing by *identity* not *equality*) `param = self.a` Why do you think it's *"ugly"*?

Comment: That's really the best you can do. Default parameters like `param=[]` face the same issue, sadly.

Comment: @Mauris thanks for the quick confirmation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe because I will have 4 lines (param1, param2....)

Comment: You could have one line each if you used `**kwargs` instead, e.g. `a = kwargs.get('a', self.a)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first attempt is pythonic, the only thing I would change is the test:

```
 def testfunc(self, param = None):
        if param is None:
            param = self.a
        print(param)
```

The problem with testing for `False` is that zero and an empty container (including an empty string) all resolve to `False`.

If you have a large number of these, see [Understanding kwargs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

If your function takes 4 arguments, and all 4 are optional and have matching properties on the object itself, then you can make this simpler by using keyword arguments:

```
def testfunc(self, **kwargs):
    a, b, c, d = [kwargs.get(name, getattr(self, name)
                  for name in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')]
```

You'd then need to call this using keyword arguments:

```
obj.testfunc()  # all values are defaults
obj.testfunc(a=1)  # a=1, all other values are defaults
obj.testfunc(b=2, d=5)  # etc.
```